# Cannot convert to icomparer array.sort C#

Tags: c#, console-application

It gives a 1503 error, but I can’t fix it. It gives an error from  Array.Sort(
valuePerWeight, weights, **values**);  in the values variable. How can I fix it? I tried to write values in front of weights but it doesn’t work

```
 class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] data = ReadDataFromFile("items.txt");
        int capacity = data[0];
        int[] weights = new int[data.Length - 1];
        int[] values = new int[data.Length - 1];
        for (int i = 1; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            weights[i - 1] = data[i];
            values[i - 1] = data[++i];
        }
        int[] selectedItems = GreedyKnapsack(capacity, weights, values);
        int totalValue = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Selected items:");
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.Length; i++)
        {
            if (selectedItems[i] == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Weight: {weights[i]}, Value: {values[i]}");
                totalValue += values[i];
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Total value: {totalValue}");
    }
```

it gives an error in array.sort

```
static int[] GreedyKnapsack(int capacity, int[] weights, int[] values)  
    {
        int n = weights.Length;
        int[] selected = new int[n]; 
        double[] valuePerWeight = new double[n]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            valuePerWeight[i] = (double)values[i] / weights[i]; 
        }
        Array.Sort(
            valuePerWeight, weights, values); 
        int weight = 0;
        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (weight + weights[i] <= capacity) 
            {
                selected[i] = 1; 
                weight += weights[i]; 
            }
        }
        return selected;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please update with a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Is it okay now? My english and programming skills is bad sorry about that

Comment: What do you expect from this line? `Array.Sort(valuePerWeight, weights, values);` If you want to sort `valuePerWeight`, just write `Array.Sort(valuePerWeight)`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `CS1503` because you are passing an array of int `Values` when you should be passing an `IComparer<int>`.

From you question, it´s not clear what's the objective of your method.
If you want to sort `valuePerWeight, weights and values`, you can just sort them seperately:

```
Array.Sort(valuePerWeight)
Array.Sort(weights)
Array.Sort(values)
```